# Difference between "I will do" and "I am going to do"?

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

In French it is "Je ferai" and "Je vais faire."

How can you tell which one to use in English?

Edit:
Does [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will)  answer it well in your opinion?

Comment: Much as you do in French - intuitively.

Comment: @WS2 I believe that in French you have to do it - intuitivement, mais oui?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["going to" vs "will"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will)

Comment: Unfortunately, "intuitively" isn't a helpful answer if your intuition doesn't tell you the right answer.

Comment: From what I know of French, using *aller* as an auxiliary in the manner that we use *go* is similar, but French appears to use it more often.  For example *Je vais telephoner à Jeanne en quinze minutes* would usually translate *I will call Jeanne in fifteen minutes*.

Comment: As for the link that you provide, I think it does a very good job of answering your question.  Kathryn's "'Going to' is a kind of present tense, so use 'going to' in situations where the present is connected to the future" is a useful way of thinking about the distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I will fix breakfast" indicates that I will (more or less) definitely produce a meal, though possibly not until after my mid-morning nap.  "I am going to fix breakfast" indicates that I fully intend to cook something, probably fairly soon, though I may need to trim my beard, polish my nails, and read the newspaper first, and there's a risk I'll end up forgetting about the cooking task.

Both forms have potential (dependent on context and tone) to be "weasel words", though "will" (especially if emphasized) conveys more determination while "going to" indicates a bit more urgency.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is often in the procrastination
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrastination
that does not exist if one is on the way to do something.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: Which one is "on the way to do something"?  The simple future or the present progressive?

Comment: I say it is the present progressive?

Comment: Tomorrow I will go to into the forest whether it is not raining and  if I don't have lost my umbrella thus I am not sure at all.